# (Odoo) Why can't i connect to the server when using pganonymizer?

Tags: subprocess, odoo

I am trying to anonymize some data in my database but I am getting the following [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5iic.png).

Postgres is running on port 5432 in the container and I am exposing it on the host on port 5433.

```
ports:
  - "5433:5432"
```

Am I supposed to add something in my odoo.conf file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newest version of pganonymizer needs you to specify the postgres hostname and port in the subprocess command.

```
        if env.get('PGHOST'):
            cmd.extend(['--host', env['PGHOST']])
        if env.get('PGPORT'):
            cmd.extend(['--port', env['PGPORT']])
```